# What does / symbol mean in UML

Tags: android, uml

I was trying to follow the uml diagram from this link http://www.uml-diagrams.org/android-camera-uml-class-diagram-example.html. 
In the CameraDemo class we find "/" after every access specifiers like +,#,_ for methods such as onStart(),onStop(). 
(Example: #/onStart() )
What does "/" mean in there.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: See [uml-diagrams.org: UML Derived Property](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/derived-property.html)

Comment: @xmojmr --Thanks ..  the answer was right in that site and I dint see it.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/` in attributes is used to indicate **Derived** but that property does not exist for operations.

I can't find any explanation of the symbol in the specifications, so we can only assume it it part of the name.

The specs (UML v2.5) state:

> 9.6.4 Notation If shown in a diagram, an Operation is shown as a text string of the form:
>
> `[<visibility>] <name> ‘(‘ [<parameter-list>] ‘)’ [‘:’ [<return-type>] [‘[‘ <multiplicity-range> ‘]’] [‘{‘ <oper-property> [‘,’ <oper-property>]* ‘}’]]`
>
> where:
>
> - `<visibility>` is the visibility of the Operation (see 7.4). 
>     `<visibility> ::= ‘+’ | ‘-‘ | ‘#’ | ‘~’`
> - `<name>` is the name of the Operation.
> - `<parameter-list>` is a list of Parameters of the Operation
>     in the following format: `<parameter-list> ::= <parameter> [‘,’<parameter>]*` where `<parameter>` is defined in 9.4.4.
> - `<return-type>` is the type of the return result Parameter if the
>     Operation has one defined.
> - `<multiplicity-range>` is the multiplicity of the return type (see 7.5).
> - `<oper-property>` indicates the properties of the Operation. 
>     `<oper-property> ::= ‘redefines’ <oper-name> | ‘query’ | ‘ordered’ | ‘unordered’ | ‘unique’ | ‘nonunique’ | ‘seq’ | ‘sequence’ | <oper-constraint>`

So no sign of Derived or `/`

Comment: I guess they mean sort of "derived operation" since the methods are inherited from the general class. It might either be some older UML syntax or a wrong interpretation. Worth a note to the umldiagrams authors.